# Not able to start Kafka-Minion container

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

Not able to start kafka-minion container.

Getting

```
{"level":"fatal","msg":"Error parsing env vars into opts. required key KAFKA_BROKERS missing value","time":"2020-12-19T05:16:32Z"}
```

I am running below command:

> docker run -ti --rm -p 9408:9408 toomasj/kafka-minion --kafka.server=XXX.XXX.XX.X:9092 --KAFKA_BROKERS=0:9092

**here:**
9408 is the port where i am exposing the minion for Prometheus.
and in "KAFKA_BROKERS=0:9092" 0 is the broker id.

Answer (score 1):

The way to pass env variables to docker containers is using one of these:

- `--env <KEY>=<VALUE>`
- `-e <KEY>=<VALUE>`

So the correct syntax for your command would be:

```
docker run -ti --rm -p 9408:9408 --env KAFKA_BROKERS=0:9092 
toomasj/kafka-minion  --kafka.server=XXX.XXX.XX.X:9092
```

or

```
docker run -ti --rm -p 9408:9408 -e KAFKA_BROKERS=0:9092
toomasj/kafka-minion --kafka.server=XXX.XXX.XX.X:9092
```

Check the [documentation here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) for more info about docker run commands.

*Thanks to OneCricketeer for correcting me, I initially put the env part at the end of the command, which is incorrect. The syntax is `docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]`. Setting the env is part of the OPTIONS block. My bad!*